# Using a coroutine for Python's Cmd class input stream

Tags: python, ssh, async-await, stdin

The problem I am facing is that:

- I have an asynchronous method
- Calling plain-old python code I cannot change
- Which calls back a plain-old python method
- Which needs to call async code using `await`

I have a custom command interpreter built on top of [Python's Cmd class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html). I provide it with custom stdin and stdout. For the purpose of this question, it looks like this:

```
import cmd
import sys

class CustomStream(object):
    def readline(self):
        return sys.stdin.readline()
    def write(self, msg):
        sys.stdout.write(msg)
    def flush(self):
        pass

class MyShell(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_stuff(self, args):
        print("Getting things done...")
    def do_exit(self, args):
        return True

stream = CustomStream()
shell = MyShell(stdin=stream, stdout=stream)
shell.use_rawinput = False 
shell.cmdloop()
```

When `Cmd` needs to read from the user, it will do this:

```
line = self.stdin.readline()
```

I want to provide an SSH interface to my custom interperter using the AsyncSSH library based on `asyncio`. My SSH code is much like the [Simple Server sample](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#simple-server-with-input), which reads a stdin like interface like this (notice the `await` keyword):

```
line_from_client = (await self._process.stdin.readline()).rstrip('\n')
```

I tried a number of things but I can't duck type the SSH code to Cmd's expectation of stdin. What must I do to have my `CustomStream` object use asyncio/coroutines on the inside while providing an old-school, single thread interface to `MyShell`?

Comment: This reddit thread sums up everything I tried so far... https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6m826s/calling_async_functions_from_synchronous_functions/

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to patch the `cmdloop` method to make it asyncio aware.

This code is a copy of Python's 3.7.2 Cmd class cmdloop function you get if you set

- `raw_input` set to `True`
- put `await` in front of readline

Results in this code ([aoicmd.py available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/ixe013/bcc2ccc2a5601004d4de29076d029c46)):

```
async def adapter_cmdloop(self, intro=None):
    """Repeatedly issue a prompt, accept input, parse an initial prefix
    off the received input, and dispatch to action methods, passing them
    the remainder of the line as argument.

    """
    self.preloop()

    #This is the same code as the Python 3.7.2 Cmd class, with the
    #following changes
    #  - Remove dead code caused by forcing use_rawinput=False.
    #  - Added a readline in front of readline()
    if intro is not None:
        self.intro = intro
    if self.intro:
        self.stdout.write(str(self.intro)+"\n")
    stop = None
    while not stop:
        if self.cmdqueue:
            line = self.cmdqueue.pop(0)
        else:
            self.stdout.write(self.prompt)
            self.stdout.flush()
            line = await self.stdin.readline()
            if not len(line):
                line = 'EOF'
            else:
                line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
        line = self.precmd(line)
        stop = self.onecmd(line)
        stop = self.postcmd(stop, line)
    self.postloop()
```

Where you need to use your Cmd derived class, like `MyShell`, create a new class called `MyAsyncShell` at runtime:

```
#Patch the shell with async aware cmdloop
MyAsyncShell = type('MyAsyncSHell', (MyShell,), {
    'cmdloop' :aiocmd.adapter_cmdloop,
    'use_rawinput':False,
})
```

Implement `write` and `flush` as you see fit, but your readline should look like this:

```
async def readline(self):
    return await my_implementation_of_readline()
```